# Swift 4 Delegate doesn't work from childViewController

Tags: swift, macos, delegates, viewcontroller

I have to code simple program. Just one login screen waiting for some password and after setting proper one, change screen to "program itself" and its features.
I decided to do it by container View and its subviews. everything works fine but delegate which should be responsible for triggering this change doesn't respond. In any option I tried, nothing has changed... it still doesn't respond.

This is code of ViewController (main):

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var container: NSView!

        var vc1 : ViewController1 = ViewController1()
        var vc2 : ViewController2 = ViewController2()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            //initialise of delegate:
            vc1.delegate = self

            // set subviews:
            vc1 = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "ViewController1")) as! ViewController1
            vc2 = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "ViewController2")) as! ViewController2
            self.addChildViewController(vc1)
            self.addChildViewController(vc2)

            // set first view:
            vc1.view.frame = self.container.bounds
            self.container.addSubview(vc1.view)
        }

        func changeViews()
        {
            for sView in self.container.subviews {
                sView.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            // set second view:
            vc2.view.frame = self.container.bounds
            self.container.addSubview(vc2.view)
        }
    }

    extension ViewController: ViewController1_Delegate {
        func passwdEntered(_ correctPasswd: Bool) {
            if correctPasswd == true{
                changeViews()
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is First (SubView) ViewController code, where I'm entering passwd:

```
import Cocoa

protocol ViewController1_Delegate: class {
    func passwdEntered(_ correctPasswd: Bool)
}

class ViewController1: NSViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: PasswordField!

    weak var delegate: ViewController1_Delegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func passwordFIeldEdited(_ sender: PasswordField) {
        delegate?.passwdEntered(true/*for testing purpose always true*/)
    }
}
```

Finally Second (SubView) ViewController code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController2: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you say this:

```
var vc1 : ViewController1 = ViewController1()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    vc1.delegate = self
```

Then you say this:

```
    vc1 = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), 
                       bundle: nil).instantiateController(
                           withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(
                               rawValue: "ViewController1")) as! ViewController1
```

So, you set yourself as delegate on a ViewController1 instance, but then, in the very next line, you *throw away* that ViewController1 and replace it with another!

Move the line `v1.delegate = self` down to *after* you set the real value of `vc1`.

Comment: Amazing!!! :-) I suspected that there is some simple solution but I didn't thing that that simple :-D Thank you a lot!!! :-) :-) :-)